# jquery mobile tap event fires once then causes problems

Tags: jquery, ipad, jquery-mobile, scrollto

I have a tap event bound to an image. The document should scroll when the image is tapped. Working on an ipad with iOS5 the function works fine the first time the image is tapped but if the user taps the image a second time consecutively the function fails. If the user taps persistently the function seems to fire again, but fails to scroll the full pixel distance defined in the function.

If the user taps the image, touches the screen to physically scroll the page, and then later taps the image a second time the function fires as it should. Why does my code work in the second case but not the first? The non-mobile version works just fine.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function () {
        $('#down_button').bind('tap', function() {
            $.scrollTo( '+=1024px', {axis: 'y', duration:300} );
        });

        $('#up_button').bind('tap', function() {
            $.scrollTo( '-=1024px', {axis: 'y', duration:300} );
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "user taps the image a second time consecutively" a double tap? Or second tap after the document completes scroll?

Comment: try it without the window.load wrapper

Answer (score 0):

You're not displaying the associated HTML so I'm going to guess that one of these elements might be nested inside another element.

If that's the case then the tap event is likely bubbling up. You can prevent this from happening by adding event.stopPropagation() to one, or both, of your event handlers. This would also require that you alter the function to pass in the event, like so:

```
.bind('tap', function(event) {
```

Comment: I'll have to try this at some point. I was actually using a fixed width document and eventually I read that fixed width documents don't support scrolling in mobile webkit so I assumed that was the problem. Though it was odd I can get some scrolling to work.